# Iterated names are not displaying using ngFor in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular2. I wanted to display the list of items . In my **first-angular-js-2-application.js** file I have done as under

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'first-angular-js-2-application'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'first-angular-js-2-application.html'
})

export class FirstAngularJs2Application {

  constructor() {
    console.info('FirstAngularJs2Application Component Mounted Successfully');

     public products = [
                     {name: "Butter"},
                     {name: "Milk"},
                     {name: "Yogurt"},
                     {name: "Cheese"},
                  ];
  }
}
```

and in **first-angular-js-2-application.html** I have

```
<h1><b><font color="blue">Product names</font></b></h1>
<ul>
              <li *ngFor="#p of products" >
                  {{ p.name }}
              </li>
           </ul>
```

Now when I run the application, it is not displaying the product names.

What wrong I am making?

N.B.~ I have generated Angular2 application through Yoeman

Comment: Please fix your code. Is `public products` inside constructor?

Comment: yes it is inside the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<li *ngFor="let p of products" >
                  {{ p.name }}
              </li>
```

I have created a plnkr but it is final version of angular2

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GzcU5wN6l9yyRdGXJOcm?p=preview)

Comment: I receive this error EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("<h1><b><font color="blue">Product names</font></b></h1>
<ul>
              <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let p of products" >
                  {{ p.name }}
              </li>

Comment: He uses old version `'angular2/core'`

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar : Are you using final version of angular 2?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: See the plunker

Comment: @santosh singh, i checked my package.json and it is  "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",...how can i upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar:npm update --save will update all packages inside package.json to their latest version according to their defined version range in package.josn

Comment: @santosh singh, just 1 more thing.. how to add a style sheet and external js to angular 2?

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar: two way to add stylesheet.you can use stylesheet per component /or you can refer external stylesheet.check this https://plnkr.co/edit/GzcU5wN6l9yyRdGXJOcm?p=preview

Comment: you can link the external style using styleUrls:["style.css"] check out this https://plnkr.co/edit/GzcU5wN6l9yyRdGXJOcm?p=preview